# Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am currently learning swift, I was trying to make a simple app that shows whether or not you are connected to the internet but I keep getting the following error:

Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

This is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let NetworkMonitor = NWPathMonitor(requiredInterfaceType: .wifi)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {                                        //Line with the error
        
            Text("Network Check")
            
            NetworkMonitor.pathUpdateHandler = {path in
                if path.status == .satisfied {
                    Text("We are Connected")
                } else {
                    Text("We are not connected")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had tried removing the VStack and the "Network Check" text but it sends another error on the *var body: some View* line:

Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type

Thanks

Comment: Error is in `NetworkMonitor.pathUpdateHandler =`, it is not allowed to use expressions in view builder blocks, only views. As well as views (Text in this case) inside callback does nothing, because they are views. Read about `@State` and how to update views.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are calling a function, you can't do it inside your view construction, try called it inside onAppear:

```
struct ContentView: View {

 let NetworkMonitor = NWPathMonitor(requiredInterfaceType: .wifi)
    @State var status = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Network Check")
            if status {
                Text("We are Connected")
            } else {
                Text("We are not connected")
            }
            
        }.onAppear() {
           NetworkMonitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            self.status = path.status == .satisfied
            }
        }
    }


}
```