# Please help: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

Tags: swift

I am trying to write code containing an If statement which depends on the responses entered by user for a series of questions. Different responses will add different values to variable "Score". My code is fairly simple, but I cannot figure why the error message "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols" keeps popping up around my If statement. The If statement is at the very end. Thank you to anyone who is willing to help!

```
import SwiftUI

struct InfluenceLevel: View {
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var age = "0"
    @State private var gender = ""
    @State private var nationality = ""
    @State private var Instagram = ""
    @State private var Celebrities = ""
    @State private var Time = ""
    @State private var products = ""
    @State private var score = 0

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Please fill out the following questions to the best of your ability, allowing us to assess your susceptibility to advertising on social media")

            Form{
                Group{
                    
                    
                    
                    Text("What is your gender? \(gender)" )
                    TextField("(Male/Female/Other):", text: $gender)
                    
                    
                    
                    Text("Are you Chinese? \(nationality)" )
                    TextField("(Yes/No):", text: $nationality)
                    
                    
                    Text("Do you use Instagram? \(Instagram)" )
                    TextField("(Yes/No):", text: $Instagram)
                }
                Group{
                    
                    Text("Do you mainly follow celebrities on social media? \(Celebrities)" )
                    TextField("(Yes/No):", text: $Celebrities)
                    
                
                    Text("Do you spend less than an hour on social media every day? \(Time)" )
                    TextField("(Yes/No)", text: $Time)
                    
                    Text("Do you use more than half of your monthly expenditure on stuff seen online? \(products)" )
                    TextField("(Yes/No)", text: $products)
                    
                    
                
                
                }
            }
        }
            .navigationBarTitle("Level of Influence")
        if gender == "Male" {
            score = score + 1
        }
    }
}

struct InfluenceLevel_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        InfluenceLevel()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use an enum to represent constrained values like Gender and Nationality, because right now your program won't work as-intended if someone types in `"male"` instead of `"Male"` (as `gender == "Male"` is case-sensitive).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63000456/type-cannot-conform-to-view-only-struct-enum-class-types-can-conform-to)

Comment: Also, I'm curious why your program thinks that males are better influencers than women...

Comment: @Dai. I am very new to swift programming. Could you please show me how I would do that? Thank you so much

Comment: @Dai. Haha, this is based on a small survey I did with a group of students in our school. And I'm basing the results of this quiz on the data collected from the survey. It's not personal bias. Also the level of influence is not the level of influence that a gender has, it's the level of influence that social media has on each gender. These questions are designed to help people understand how susceptible they are to advertising on social media based on data we have gathered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
enum GenderEnum: Int {
    case female, male, other
    
    init(str: String) {
        switch str {
        case "Male":
            self = .male
        case "Female":
            self = .female
        default:
            self = .other
        }
    }
}

struct InfluenceLevel: View {
    @State private var gender = ""
    @State private var score = 0

    
    var body: some View {
                
        let binding = Binding<String>(get: {
                    self.gender
                }, set: {
                    self.gender = $0
                    score = GenderEnum(str: $0).rawValue
                    print(score)
                })
        
        VStack {
            Text("Please fill out the following questions to the best of your ability, allowing us to assess your susceptibility to advertising on social media")

            Form{
                Group{
                    
                    Text("What is your gender? \(gender)" )
                    TextField("(Male/Female/Other):", text: binding)
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Level of Influence")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Me Mayani. But how would I be able to show the person's final score, and how can I do this for each question (i.e. nationality, age etc).

Comment: It's just example of one variable, you can use multiple times or multiply for all.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how I can add more points depending on what their answer is? I'm very new to Swift, so I'm finding it a bit difficult to understand how your code works. Thank you!